# Could not find method: coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled in the gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle

I want to use **Android Studio 4.0 Canary 3**

as in the, [features list](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#j8-desugar) has mentioned:

> Android Studio now includes support for using a number of Java 8
>   language APIs without requiring a minimum API level for your app.

with adding this method `coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled` with a `true` argument into the `compileOptions` object, in the module’s build.gradle file.

like this:

```
 compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
```

I expected it would work fine, but it makes the below error:

*`Could not find method coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled() for arguments [true] on object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.CompileOptions.`*

Comment: I have the same issue with AGP 4 canary 5. I accepted the IDE update indicator and let it upgrade to `com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0-alpha05` and gradle 6.1-milestone-1. I also recreated the project too.

Comment: as @akarnokd said, you need Gradle 4 in alpha version at the moment

Answer (score 18):

What about if you use `isCoreLibraryDesugaringEnabled`?

Comment: Bull's Eye! You were right. I have noticed these changes in recent gradle upgrades. I am on plugin 4.1.1 version 6.5

Comment: This worked for me. Currently on Gradle version 7.2

Answer (score 7):

You should use latest Gradle service version > 6.3 (Gradle wrapper file) and Gradle build version > 4.1.0 alpha (app.gradle file) in order to work desugaring.

Here build.gradle screenshot as described at [Google guide](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features)

[image: build Gradle settings]

Comment: Here is guide how to do it by Google:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=heCvGfOGH0s

Comment: What is the gradle build version? I don't have an app.gradle file

Comment: Found it, it was in android/app/build.gradle

Comment: + this as well: https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/could-not-find-method-corelibrarydesugaringenabled/

Answer (score 7):

use this in build.gradle:

```
    compileOptions {
        // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
        coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
        // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

dependencies {
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.1.5'
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Answer from dankawka on https://github.com/juliuscanute/qr_code_scanner/issues/325, read to make sure your problem is actually the same.

You have to upgrade Gradle, Kotlin and Kotlin Gradle Plugin:

- In android/build.gradle bump `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'` to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.5.10'`
- In android/build.gradle bump `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.0'`
- In android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties bump `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.2-all.zip` to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-all.zip`

Answer (score -4):

You have change Source Compatibility and Target Compatibility to 1.8 in the Project Structure dialog as shown in figure 2 (click File > Project Structure) in Android Studio